# I would like the send button to be inactive until the user key in something in the textbox. How can I do this?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace SocketClient
{

    public partial class SocketClient : Form
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
        string readData = null;


        public SocketClient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void getMessage()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                int buffSize = 0;
                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
                string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                readData = "" + returndata;
                msg();
            }
        }


        private void msg()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(msg));
            else
                textDisplay.Text = textDisplay.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData;
        }


        private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            readData = "Conected to NYP Chat Server ...";
            msg();
            clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textName.Text + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
            ctThread.Start();
        }


        private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // send text
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textSend.Text + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
            //clear textsend textbox
            textSend.Text = "";

        }

        private void textDisplay_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textDisplay.SelectionStart = textDisplay.Text.Length;
            textDisplay.ScrollToCaret();
            textDisplay.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign this event handler to the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event of the textbox and set the `Enabled` property of the button initially to false.

```
private void textSend_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonSend.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textSend.Text);
}
```

Comment: bro once again thanks, Another qns is that if i am not connected to my server and type some text in the send text n press send, the will be a warning showing in my program "serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);" << NullreferenceException is unhandled. is there anyway to prevent this warning from showing?

Comment: Insert a check whether `serverStream` is a null reference.

Comment: how to do this, sorry i kinda noob

Comment: `if (serverStream == null) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: under where do i insert the check?

Comment: ok what do i need to replace the ... as i really donoe what to input. sorry